# 'Error: no root objects' running monero-wallet-gui in Ubuntu 16.04 x64 on Asus UX410U

Tags: compiling, gui

I installed Monero GUI as per the instructions on the [Monero github page](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui)

These were the steps:

1. Install Monero dependencies

For Ubuntu and Mint

> sudo apt install build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libzmq3-dev

2. Grab an up-to-date copy of the monero-gui repository

> git clone https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui.git

3. Go into the repository

> cd monero-gui

4. Install the GUI dependencies

For Ubuntu 16.04+ x64

> sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qttools5-dev-tools qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qt-labs-settings libqt5qml-graphicaleffects

5. Build the GUI:

> ./build.sh

Build finished without error and as instructed went to build/release/bin and ran the executable (monero-wallet-gui), resulting in error as follows:

```
cd build/release/bin
./monero-wallet-gui

app startd
Qt:5.5.1 | screen: 1920x1080 - dpi: 96 - ratio:1.23591
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:///main.qml:1811 Type DaemonConsole unavailable
qrc:///components/DaemonConsole.qml:30 module "QtQuick.Controls" version 2.0 is not installed

Error: no root objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Per a monero-gui contributor, [building for Ubuntu 16.04 is no longer supported](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/1370). There are a few ways you could potentially work around the problem. Below is a copy/paste of the comment by pazos.

> Ubuntu 16.04 is not supported anymore. It doesn't have the minimum QT required by the application to run, which is QT 5.7.0. Official releases work because they ship qt bundled inside the application.
>
> The are three things you can do:
>
> 1. use official builds, don't try to build from source.
> 2. upgrade your ubuntu box to -at least- ubuntu 17.10.
> 3. download qt official releases for linux-x64 from download.qt.io and install it somewhere on your path. Use that qt version to link your program.
>
> I don't suggest to try 3 if you don't understand what it means. The README should be updated to specify all those changes.